# Python How to create and join user servers/lobbies. To then enable users to call functions which effect the users in that lobby/server?

Tags: python

I have a python login system where users create an account, which is stored in database.

I wish to enable users with an account to create, join and invite other users into their own lobby/group. Whereby I can then allow users in that lobby to call a function that effects the users inside of that lobby and not all users in the database.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: look more into discord groups and it;s functionalities

Comment: This question is very broad and open-ended. There's really no way to answer this, as written. You've also shown no code, inputs, expected vs actual outputs, errors, or any other details (and it seems, based on your question, that you have indeed created *something*). Please edit to provide all relevant details.

Comment: **This question is very broad and open-ended. ** Asking us Questions to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets python library was what I was looking for. You can enable users to create game lobbies/servers. And then have the users call functions within those servers.